# An already created maven project : where to find its artifactId and groupId

Tags: maven, m2eclipse

I have a ready maven project and i want to know its artifactId and groupId 
Have you any idea how to do it?

Thank you in advace

Answer (score 1):

It is in the pom.xml in the root directory of your project, near the top of the file:

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>HERE</groupId>
<artifactId>AND HERE</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
```

Comment: i found the name entered by the user and not the type of the maven project (artifactId and GroupID)

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.selenium.tests</groupId>
  <artifactId>seleniumproject</artifactId>